# Common elements between two lists not using sets in Python

Tags: python, list, set

I want count the same elements of two lists. Lists can have duplicate elements, so I can't convert this to sets and use & operator.

```
a=[2,2,1,1]
b=[1,1,3,3]
```

set(a) & set(b) work
a & b don't work

It is possible to do it withoud set and dictonary?

Comment: Why don't you want to use sets?

Comment: I have duplicate elements in list

Comment: what is the expected return values for `[1, 2, 1]` and `[1, 3, 2]`?

Comment: ... and what's the desired output for `[1, 2, 2]` and `[1, 1, 2]`?

Comment: I guess he expects `[1, 2]` in both cases

Comment: Based on a comment below, he wants [1,2,1] in the first case. It's still unclear what he wants for the second.

Answer (score 12):

In Python 3.x (and Python 2.7, when it's released), you can use [collections.Counter](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) for this:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> list((Counter([2,2,1,1]) & Counter([1,3,3,1])).elements())
[1, 1]
```

Here's an alternative using [collections.defaultdict](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) (available in Python 2.5 and later).  It has the nice property that the order of the result is deterministic (it essentially corresponds to the order of the second list).

```
from collections import defaultdict

def list_intersection(list1, list2):
    bag = defaultdict(int)
    for elt in list1:
        bag[elt] += 1

    result = []
    for elt in list2:
        if elt in bag:
            # remove elt from bag, making sure
            # that bag counts are kept positive
            if bag[elt] == 1:
                del bag[elt]
            else:
                bag[elt] -= 1
            result.append(elt)

    return result
```

For both these solutions, the number of occurrences of any given element `x` in the output list is the minimum of the numbers of occurrences of `x` in the two input lists.  It's not clear from your question whether this is the behavior that you want.

Comment: `if bag[elt]:` adds an item `elt: 0` to the bag when `elt in bag` is false. When (as the OP hinted) there are few duplicates, it may be better to do `if elt in bag and bag[elt]:` otherwise bag may become bloated with useless 0 values.

Comment: @John Machin:  Hmm.  Good point.  An alternative would be to make sure that bag counts are always strictly positive, by following `bag[elt] -= 1` with  an `if not bag[elt]: del bag[elt]`.  Then the `if` test could just be `if elt in bag:`, which reads more nicely.

I'll edit the answer.

Answer (score 8):

Using sets is the most efficient, but you could always do `r = [i for i in l1 if i in l2]`.

Comment: A distinct difference: The suggested set() & set() method will return a single value that is common between the two lists (set([1]) in this example) whereas your solution will return [1, 1] and so on.

Comment: Thanks, but is it some more perfomence solution?

Comment: I want function which return [1,1]

Comment: @Thomas:  This solution gives `[1, 1]` if `l1 == [1, 1]` and `l2 == [1]`, but it gives `[1]` if `l1 == [1]` and `l2 == [1, 1]`.  Is that the behavior that you want?

Answer (score 0):

SilentGhost, Mark Dickinson and Lo'oris are right, Thanks very much for report this problem - I need common part of lists, so for:

a=[1,1,1,2]

b=[1,1,3,3]

result should be [1,1]

Sorry for comment in not suitable place - I have registered today.

I modified yours solutions:

```
def count_common(l1,l2):
        l2_copy=list(l2)
        counter=0
        for i in l1:
            if i in l2_copy:
                counter+=1
                l2_copy.remove(i)
        return counter

l1=[1,1,1]
l2=[1,2]
print count_common(l1,l2)
```

---

1

Comment: welcome!  You might want to email `team@stackoverflow.com`  and ask them to merge your newly registered account with the previous temporary account.  See:
http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18232/how-can-one-link-merge-combine-associate-two-stack-overflow-accounts-users-anon