# What is the Pythonic way to find the longest common prefix of a list of lists?

Tags: python

**Given**:  a list of lists, such as `[[3,2,1], [3,2,1,4,5], [3,2,1,8,9], [3,2,1,5,7,8,9]]`

**Todo**:   Find the longest common prefix of all sublists.

**Exists**: In another thread "[Common elements between two lists not using sets in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2727650/common-elements-between-two-lists-not-using-sets-in-python)", it is suggested to use "Counter", which is available above python 2.7. However our current project was written in python 2.6, so "Counter" is not used.

**I currently code it like this:**

```
l = [[3,2,1], [3,2,1,4,5], [3,2,1,8,9], [3,2,1,5,7,8,9]]
newl = l[0]
if len(l)>1:
    for li in l[1:]:
    newl = [x for x in newl if x in li]
```

But I find it not very pythonic, is there a better way of coding?

Thanks!

**New edit**: Sorry to mention: in my case, the shared elements of the lists in 'l' have the same order and alway start from the 0th item. So you wont have cases like `[[1,2,5,6],[2,1,7]]`

Comment: What is the expected output for `[[1, 2, 3], [3, 2, 1]]`?

Comment: `Counter` doesn't preserve order anyway. What are the common elements between `[3, 2, 1]` and `[4, 3, 2, 1]`? `[]` or `[3, 2, 1]`? I'm asking -- does position matter as well as order? If position doesn't matter, then it's the [Longest common substring problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_substring_problem) which you can find the answer to elsewhere on this site

Comment: what is expected output of [[1,2,3],[1,4,2,3]]

Comment: Please see my New edit in the original post.

Comment: @lukmac: I tried to clarify the title and the post.  Please check if this is what you want.

Comment: Yes, your edit fits it better, thanks

Comment: Just to be clear, should `[[1, 2, 3], [1, 8, 2, 3]]` generate output (a) `[1]` or (b) `[1, 2, 3]`? Because your example code returns (b), but your title suggests that you want to return (a).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I am not sure how pythonic it is

```
from itertools import takewhile,izip

x = [[3,2,1], [3,2,1,4,5], [3,2,1,8,9], [3,2,1,5,7,8,9]]

def allsame(x):
    return len(set(x)) == 1

r = [i[0] for i in takewhile(allsame ,izip(*x))]
```

Comment: Sorry for the bother, but i'm having a similar problem. I have to find the longest common prefix on a (single) list, but the prefix isn't exactly going to be on **every** element on the list. Could you guide me a little in order to make it work, or should I post a new question?

Comment: Also, I wanted to try this code, but i'm also using Python 3.6.2. I saw that now **`izip`** isn't in *itertools* anymore, because now there is a main function called **`zip`** that does so. I tried replacing it but now I get `TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'` **on** `return len(set(x)) == 1`. Do you know how to adapt it to work in Python 3?

Comment: About python3 I think that you can use build-in zip function, but I do not know sure if your code is same as one posted in this answer, because I do not get such error. About your first question I do not understand it well and you can post new question on SO.

Comment: [`more_itertools`](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/_modules/more_itertools/more.html#longest_common_prefix) now implements this

Answer (score 66):

[`os.path.commonprefix()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.commonprefix) works well for lists :)

```
>>> x = [[3,2,1], [3,2,1,4,5], [3,2,1,8,9], [3,2,1,5,7,8,9]]
>>> import os
>>> os.path.commonprefix(x)
[3, 2, 1]
```

Comment: Pretty neat and doesn't require any extra libraries!

Comment: Neat! And fast!

Comment: And `os.path.commonprefix()` works for `str` type also. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Given your example code, you seem to want a version of `reduce(set.intersection, map(set, l))` that preserves the initial order of the first list.

This requires *algorithmic* improvements, not stylistic improvements; "pythonic" code alone won't do you any good here. Think about the situation that *must* hold for all values that occur in every list:

> Given a list of lists, a value occurs in every list if and only if it occurs in `nlist` lists, where `nlist` is the total number of lists.

If we can guarantee that each value occurs only once in every list, then the above can be rephrased:

> Given a list of lists of unique items, a value occurs in every list if and only if it occurs `nlist` times total.

We can use sets to guarantee that the items in our lists are unique, so we can combine this latter principle with a simple counting strategy:

```
>>> l = [[3,2,1], [3,2,1,4,5], [3,2,1,8,9], [3,2,1,5,7,8,9]]
>>> count = {}
>>> for i in itertools.chain.from_iterable(map(set, l)):
...     count[i] = count.get(i, 0) + 1
...
```

Now all we have to do is filter the original list:

```
>>> [i for i in l[0] if count[i] == len(l)]
[3, 2, 1]
```

Comment: Well, it seems the goalposts have moved again.  +1 for a good answer to what seemed to be the question. :)

Comment: @SvenMarnach, my thinking is that "the shared elements of the lists in 'l' have the same order and alway start from the 0th item" doesn't disallow input like `[[1, 2, 3], [1, 44, 2, 3]]`. So I don't _think_ this is a longest common prefix problem. But time will tell.

Comment: My crystal ball seems to have worked fine – the OP confirmed theyy are looking for the longest common prefix.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an alternative way using itertools:

```
>>> import itertools
>>> L = [[3,2,1,4], [3,2,1,4,5], [3,2,1,8,9], [3,2,1,5,7,8,9]]
>>> common_prefix = []
>>> for i in itertools.izip(*L):
...    if i.count(i[0]) == len(i):
...       common_prefix.append(i[0])
...    else:
...       break
... 
>>> common_prefix
[3, 2, 1]
```

Not sure how "pythonic" it might be considered though.

Answer (score 0):

It is inefficient as it doesn't early-out as soon as a mismatch is found, but its tidy:

```
([i for i,(j,k) in enumerate(zip(a,b)) if j!=k] or [0])[0]
```