# Get suffix / prefix corrections from two strings to transform source string to target string in python

Tags: python, string, difflib, lcs

I need to transform a source string to target string and express the same as an operation (D,A,TYPE) ie(deletion , addition, PREFIX\SUFFIX) to the source string which will transform it to target string on applying these operation to the suffix of the source string, or the prefix of the source string

eg:

```
activities->activity
(ies,y,suffix)

center->centre
(er,re,suffix)

solutions->solution
(s,None,suffix)

solution ->solutions
(None,s,suffix)

could->would
(c,w,prefix)
```

the following code does get the suffixes but also gets all other matches but I need this only for suffixes, beside it does not output the correct format as required by me.

```
from difflib import SequenceMatcher
a = "ACTIVITY"
b = "ACTIVITIES"


s = SequenceMatcher(None, a, b)
for tag, i1, i2, j1, j2 in s.get_opcodes():
   print ("%7s a[%d:%d] (%s) b[%d:%d] (%s)" %
          (tag, i1, i2, a[i1:i2], j1, j2, b[j1:j2]))
```

Also I don't need any corrections to be output if there is no sufficient suffix/prefix match eg: strings like enough, beyond should yield no match, Which can be possibly gleaned from:

```
difflib.SequenceMatcher(None,'especially','particularly').ratio()
```

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't need difflib as it can be done by finding the common prefix or suffix and removing that from the strings. Consider:

```
>>> from os.path import commonprefix
>>> c = commonprefix(['activities', 'activity'])
>>> c
'activit'
>>> [v[len(c):] for v in ['activities', 'activity']]
['ies', 'y']
```

As I don't have a `commonsuffix` function, I simply reverse the strings and then apply the `commonprefix` function:

```
>>> c = commonprefix(['could'[::-1], 'would'[::-1]])
>>> c
'dluo'
>>> [v[len(c):][::-1] for v in ['could'[::-1], 'would'[::-1]]]
['c', 'w']
```

To combine that into a function:

```
from os.path import commonprefix

def suffix_prefix(a, b):

   pre = commonprefix([a, b])
   suf = commonprefix([a[::-1], b[::-1]])
   if len(pre) > len(suf):
       return tuple(v[len(pre):] for v in (a, b)) + ('suffix',)
   else:
       return tuple(v[len(suf):][::-1] for v in (a[::-1], b[::-1])) + ('prefix',)

print suffix_prefix('activities', 'activity')
print suffix_prefix('could', 'would')
print suffix_prefix('solutions', 'solution')
```

Prints:

```
('ies', 'y', 'suffix')
('c', 'w', 'prefix')
('s', '', 'suffix')
```

I'l leave the string formatting to you.

Answer (score 1):

I think you might be over complicating this a little. Its reasonably easy to find the shared suffix of two strings in python *without* using `difflib`. For examples see [this stackexchange question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11263172/what-is-the-pythonic-way-to-find-the-longest-common-prefix-of-a-list-of-lists). In particular this is implemented in the `os` module as `os.path.commonprefix`. Using this we can find the difference in suffix for two strings which share a prefix or the difference of the prefix in two strings that share a suffix (the second way just by reversing the strings and using the first).

Here is an example (which could certainly be neatened up):

```
import os

def find_change(string_1, string_2):
    shared_prefix = os.path.commonprefix([string_1, string_2])

    if len(shared_prefix) > 0:
        return "{}->{}\n({},{},{})".format(string_1, string_2, string_1[len(shared_prefix):],string_2[len(shared_prefix):], "SUFFIX")

    string_1_reversed = string_1[::-1]
    string_2_reversed = string_2[::-1]

    shared_suffix_reversed = shared_prefix = os.path.commonprefix([string_1_reversed, string_2_reversed])

    if len(shared_suffix_reversed) > 0:
        shared_suffix = shared_suffix_reversed[::-1]
        return "{}->{}\n({},{},{})".format(string_1, string_2, string_1[:-len(shared_suffix)], string_2[:-len(shared_suffix)], "PREFIX")

    return None 

print(find_change("could", "would"))
print(find_change("hello", "helmet"))
```

Comment: i actually wanted the ("could","c","w")) as output given could, would

Comment: thanks,the question asks to transform the two input strings to the correction output(d,e,type) which will transform the source to target