# How to get the same string repeated for all the values in a python list

Tags: python

I'm wondering which will be the best pythonic way to get all the same prefix for the values in a list.

- Rule #1: the word will be compound by the following parts: prefix + name + end (separated by '_'.
- Rule #2: all the word parts will be variable in length
- Rule #3: the end of the word is a two-character string starting with letter 'A' followed by a integer from 0-9 and could be the same for all the values in the list
- Rule #4: The names of each value will never be repeated in a list
- Rule #5: all the values in the list will have the same "unknown"
  prefix

Here are some examples from the rules listed above:

```
list1 = ['4_AR_P3_A0', '4_BCML_A0', '4_PA_RU_LR_A0', '4_Routes_A0']
get_prefix(list1) # output: '2'
list2 = ['MPL_TER_LA_Desse_A1', 'MPL_TER_LA_Magnit_Mach_A0', 'MPL_TER_LA_LR_A6', 'MPL_TER_LA_Routes_A0']
get_prefix(list2) # output: 'MPL_TER_LA'
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11263172/what-is-the-pythonic-way-to-find-the-longest-common-prefix-of-a-list-of-lists

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Pranav:

```
import os
s_l = []
for v in list1: s_l.append(v.split('_'))
print(os.path.commonprefix(s_l))
```

Answer (score 1):

use `os.path.commonprefix()`. Please check out: [os.path](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).