# Unable to create a proper set / list

Tags: python, list, set

I have two lists

```
a = [1,1,2,3]
b = [1,2]
```

I need a new list c to have the answer which is derived by removing common elements of list b from list a. Which means if b has 1,2 then after removing from a the new list should have 1,3 as elements.

```
[1,3]
```

I tried

```
d = set(a) & set(b)
c = set(a) - d
print c
```

but I got

```
[3]
```

instead of

```
[1,3]
```

I know this is because the moment i do set(a) the repeated elements are trucncated and I am left with only one copy of all elements in there.

But my problem is that I want the repeated elements should not be removed.

What to do?

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2727650/common-elements-between-two-lists-not-using-sets-in-python?rq=1

Comment: `repeated elements should not be removed` - then do not use set. The whole point of this datastructure is to remove duplicates

Comment: Why would you expect that result rather than the one you got? `set(a)` contains 1, 2 and 3, `set(b)` contains 1 and 2 so `set(d) will contain 1 and 2. Removing 1 and 2 from `set(a)` would only leave 3 which makes `set(a)-d` contains precisely 3.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) -

```
>>> a = [1,1,2,3]
>>> b = [1,2]
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> c = list((Counter(a) - Counter(b)).elements())
>>> c
[1, 3]
```

What this does is that it counts the elements in list `a` and then in list `b` , and then it decreases the count in list `a` by the count of similar elements in list `b` , and converts them back to a list and stores in `c`.

This would even work if `b` has elements that are not in `a`, example -

```
>>> a = [1,1,2,3]
>>> b = [1,2,4]
>>> list((Counter(a) - Counter(b)).elements())
[1, 3]
```

Answer (score 1):

You do not need set and other packages. Importing additional packages "may" be expensive in terms of resources.

Try this.

```
c = list(a)
for data in b:
    if data in c: 
        c.remove(data)
```

To ignore, you may use try-except block.

```
c = list(a)
for data in b:
    try:
        c.remove(data)
    except ValueError:
        pass
```

Comment: This would not work if b has an element not in a. Though I am not sure if that is a case for the OP.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `remove()` to remove just one occurrence and a loop.  For example:

```
a = [1,1,2,3]
b = [1,2]
# Create a copy of a so you don't modify a itself
c = list(a)
for num in b:
    c.remove(num)

print c
```

Answer (score 0):

`Counter` is handy for this, but it has a reputation of being quite slow.
Here is a version using `defaultdict` instead.

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> D = defaultdict(int)
>>> a = [1,1,2,3]
>>> b = [1,2]
>>> for k in a:
...     D[k] += 1
... 
>>> for k in b:
...     D[k] -= 1
... 
>>> [k for k in D for i in range(D[k])]
[1, 3]
```

Here is another way that retains the order of `a` in the result

```
>>> D = defaultdict(int)
>>> a = [1,1,2,3]
>>> b = [1,2]
>>> for k in b:
...     D[k] += 1
... 
>>> res = []
>>> for i in a:
...     if D[i]:
...         D[i] -= 1
...     else:
...         res.append(i)
... 
>>> res
[1, 3]
```