# Compare And Replace Items In List

Tags: python, list

How do you compare the objects in two lists, and then if there are two of the same objects in both lists, replace it with something? For example:

```
list1 = [a,b,c,d]
list2 = ['h','j','a','d']
```

I want to say, if some of the objects in `list1` are the same with some of the objects in `list2`, replace those objects with something else (For example, `'hello'`)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Common elements between two lists not using sets in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2727650/common-elements-between-two-lists-not-using-sets-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

```
list1 = [x if x not in list2 else 'hello' for x in list1]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) and t[he ternary operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_operation#Python).